# Cannot compute a t-test function in R Markdown

Tags: r, csv, t-test

I am trying to read some data from a csv data in R and then compute a t-test function but I am getting an error that there is an unexpected symbol in label.

This is my code :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr) 
library(dplyr)    
labels <- list('non-failing heart (NF)', 'failing heart (F)')

data <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\alex\\Downloads\\data.csv", header=T)

data[data == 'NA_integer_'] <- NA
data %>% mutate_all(as.numeric) -> data
t.test(data$NF, data$F)

df <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, 
                       lapply(data, function(d) data.frame(d[1], d[2]))),
              labels)    

                           
                           
results <- t.test(df$`non-failing heart (NF)`, df$`failing heart (F)`)


                           
results$statistic
results$estimate
results$p.value
```

and this the error :

```
Error: unexpected Symbol in:
"              labels)    
results"
> results$statistic
Error: Object 'results' not found
```

This is how my data looks like:

[image]

Comment: That is a syntax error:  it is saying that the expressions in your code are not formed properly (e.g. there is a missing comma).  It never gets to the stage of reading the dataset.  However, I don't get the error from what you posted:  you need to look for a typo in the original.

Comment: @user2554330 thanks for your comment, this is also ehat I understand from the error after some searchs in Google but I didn't find what is exactly missing, what do you mean by a typo in the original ?

Comment: I think the code where you saw the error is not identical to what you posted here, because I don't get that error from what you posted.

Comment: @user2554330 I have copied from R studio, it is the same code

Comment: Okay, but I don't understand what the connection is to R Markdown.

Comment: @user2554330 the code is written in rmd file and what is posted is a included in a form of chunk, by the way, this error is strangely gone, I am getting now some errors of :
Problem with `mutate()` input `NF.F`.
i NAs durch Umwandlung erzeugt
i Input `NF.F` is `.Primitive("as.double")(NF.F)`. 
2: In mask$eval_all_mutate(dots[[i]]) : NAs durch Umwandlung erzeugt

Comment: @user2554330 sorry I didn't remark that there is some german errors such  as durch Umwandlung erzeugt which is mean generated by conversion

Comment: @Anouar from which line does the error rise